# Firebase Authentication Limits (Daily/Monthly Active Users)

Tags: firebase, api, authentication, limit

I was wondering if anyone can clarify a Firebase Authentication API limit for me as I am a little confused.

I am developing a website that is storing the user registrations (email/password login details) in the Firebase Authentication so I don't have to store them in my local db.

I can see from their documentation that on the "Spark Plan" (free plan) I can have 49,999 Monthly Active Users and then any extra is charged. This is fine. Registered User Accounts is unlimited. This is fine. I am only using Firebase Authentication and it is purely Email/Password login - no email verifications, no SMS etc just pure Email/Password login.

What I don't understand is the following on their website:

**Instrumentless Limit:**

**Tier 1 Daily Active Users | 3000 per day**

What exactly does the above mean/restrict? Can only 3000 users login per day?
Their pricing calculator doesn't mention this, it only asks about Monthly Active Users, to which I enter say 30,000 and it calculates $0.00 monthly charge. But I don't want to go to far to be then restricted that my 30,000 Monthly Users can only allow 3000 of them per day to login.

A little confused. Hoping someone who know this stuff can advise.

Many thanks for your time.
Ro

Comment: Do you know what is tier 2 daily user ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I worked out my confusion if this helps anyone else with the same confusion. I just wasn't reading the docs correctly.

Firebase Authentication now has the Identity Platform (Google).

If you stick with the "Spark Plan" (100% free) then you get a new restriction of 3000 Daily Active User logins.

If you upgrade to the "Blaze Plan" (Pay as You Go) then you get 49,999 free Monthly Active Users (a single user can login in as many times as they want in a month and that is classed as 1 Monthly Active User) and after 49,999 then you pay per user.

So, Identity Platform for the Spark Plan is Daily Active User limits (3000) and Blaze Plan is Monthly Active Users (49,999) - for free.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: The "Spark Plan" (100% free) not restrict 3000 Daily Active User logins.